# Admin order update price programmatically in quote loop

Tags: admin, orders, price, event-observer, quote

I have a bit of custom pricing that needs to be carried out for each product in an order which alters the end price of the item.

I am using an observer with the `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` event to ensure that the price is run each time the product is re-configured, as I haven't been able to get desired results from other events.

The issue i'm running into is the inability to change the price of the product in the quote when looping through the quote using `->getAllItems()`.

I know that the price can be overridden via the following for the product add events.

```
$_item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
$_item = ( $_item->getParentItem() ? $_item->getParentItem() : $_item );
$new_price = 1000;
$_item->setCustomPrice($new_price);
$_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
$_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

However, I can not find a way to do it when running through the quote items within the cart. Is this possible, or would the pricing have to be done in a different observer, and if so, which?

Full code is below...

```
public function adminAddProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) {
    $quote = $this->_getSession()->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $_item){
        $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
        $_product = $_item->getProduct();
        $sku = $options['simple_sku'];
        if ($sku) {
            $tierPrices = $_product->getTierPrice();
            $price = $_item->getPrice();
            $qty = $options['info_buyRequest']['qty'];

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
            $runspeed = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('runspeed')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

            $prodOpts = [];
            foreach($options['options'] as $option) {
                $prodOpts[$option['label']] = $option['value'];
            }

            $index = 0;
            foreach($tierPrices as $tierPrice) {
                if($tierPrice['price_qty'] <= $qty && $tierPrices[$index + 1]['price_qty'] > $qty) {
                    $price = $tierPrice['price'];
                }
                //$prodTiers[$tierPrice['price_qty']] = $tierPrice['price'];
            }

            if($prodOpts['Quantity'] == 'Fixed Quantity' && array_key_exists('Quantity Select', $prodOpts)){
                $qty = str_replace(',', '', explode(" ", $prodOpts['Quantity Select'])[0]);
            } else {
                $qty = 1;
            }

            $_item->setQty($qty);
            $_item->setCustomPrice($customPrice)->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);

            $new_price = 999;

            $_item->setPrice($new_price);
            $_item->setCustomPrice($new_price);
            $_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
            $_item->save();

            Mage::log($price);
            Mage::log($prodOpts);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to be that `$quote->save()` needed to be appended after the `$_item->save()` method.